# C# main static class

Tags: c#

In C# main class why is not static?
Both works fine.

```
namespace CS_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace CS_Console
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

what is difference between this two one?

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you might choose to add other members to the Program class that aren't required to be static. Within the Main method you could then create an instance of the Program class and treat it like any other class.

Answer (score 2):

A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. Hence, both the code samples you have mentioned above work.

For detailed info, [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It follows the conventional coding guidelines of C#. Classes that only contain static methods should be declared as static. As `Main` must be static, it is best to declare your class as static.

`Program` can be declared as non static but as you may already know, `static Main` must remain static as it is an entry point. The responsibility of `Program` is to provide an entry point into your application and nothing more. All it needs to do that is contain one `static` method called `Main` and as `Main` is always declared as `static`, there is no reason why `Program` shouldn't be too.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229038.aspx).